# задать порядок сортировки в postgresql-функции

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет,
есть postgresql ( 9.4.10 ) - функция для считывания продуктов и данных из связанных таблиц
А можно ли порядок сортировки задать параметром (p_sort)
Я гуглом нашел ссылку https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139618/postgresql-parameterized-order-by-limit-in-table-function

И делаю :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.pd_get_product_prices(p_limit integer, p_offset integer, p_sort character varying DEFAULT 'rating', p_sort_direction character varying DEFAULT 'asc', p_title character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying, p_status type_productstatus DEFAULT NULL::type_productstatus, p_in_stock boolean DEFAULT NULL::boolean, p_sku character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying, p_sale_price_from type_money DEFAULT NULL::numeric, p_sale_price_till type_money DEFAULT NULL::numeric, p_rating_from integer DEFAULT NULL::integer, p_rating_till integer DEFAULT NULL::integer, p_category_list integer[] DEFAULT NULL::integer[])
 RETURNS TABLE(id integer, title character varying, status type_productstatus, sku character varying, user_id smallint, regular_price type_money, sale_price type_money, in_stock boolean, short_description character varying, virtual boolean, rating_count integer, rating_summary integer, rating integer, created_at timestamp without time zone, main_image character varying, product_categories character varying[], product_categories_id smallint[], product_tags character varying[], product_tags_id smallint[], product_attributes jsonb)
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$

select * from ( SELECT p.id, p.title, p.status, p.sku, p.user_id, p.regular_price, p.sale_price, p.in_stock, p.short_description, p.virtual, p.rating_count, p.rating_summary,

CAST( floor( p.rating_summary / NULLIF(p.rating_count,0)  ) AS INTEGER ) as rating,

p.created_at,
(select pi.image from pd_product_image as pi where pi.product_id = p.id and pi.is_main = true ) as main_image,
( select array_agg(c.name) from pd_category as c, pd_product_category as pd where c.id= pd.category_id and pd.product_id = p.id) as product_categories,
( select array_agg(c.id) from pd_category as c, pd_product_category as pd where c.id= pd.category_id and pd.product_id = p.id) as product_categories_id,
( select array_agg(t.name) from pd_tag as t, pd_product_tag as pt where t.id= pt.tag_id and pt.product_id = p.id) as product_tags,
( select array_agg(t.id) from pd_tag as t, pd_product_tag as pt where t.id= pt.tag_id and pt.product_id = p.id) as product_tags_id,
( select pa.attributes_data from pd_product_attribute as pa where pa.product_id = p.id) as product_attributes


FROM pd_product AS p LEFT JOIN  pd_product_category AS pc ON pc.product_id = p.id
       WHERE
           ( p.status= p_status OR p_status IS NULL ) AND
           ( p.in_stock = p_in_stock OR p_in_stock IS NULL )  AND
           ( p.sku like p_sku OR p_sku IS NULL )  AND
           ( p.title like p_title OR p_title IS NULL ) AND
           ( ( p.sale_price >= p_sale_price_from AND p.sale_price <= p_sale_price_till ) OR ( p_sale_price_from IS NULL OR p_sale_price_till IS null ) ) AND
          ( pc.category_id = ANY (p_category_list) OR p_category_list IS NULL )
       GROUP BY p.id
) as rows

       WHERE( (   rows.rating >= p_rating_from AND rows.rating <= p_rating_till ) OR ( p_rating_from IS NULL OR p_rating_till IS null ) )

       ORDER BY


      -- Simplified to NULL if not sorting in ascending order.
      CASE WHEN p_sort_direction = 'asc' THEN
          CASE p_sort
              -- Check for each possible value of p_sort.
              WHEN 'rating' THEN rating
              WHEN 'sale_price' THEN sale_price
              WHEN 'title' THEN title
              --- etc.
              ELSE NULL
          END
      ELSE
          NULL
      END
      ASC,

      -- Same as before, but for p_sort_direction = 'desc'
      CASE WHEN p_sort_direction = 'desc' THEN
          CASE p_sort
              WHEN 'rating' THEN rating
              WHEN 'sale_price' THEN sale_price
              WHEN 'title' THEN title
              ELSE NULL
          END
      ELSE
          NULL
      END
      DESC


       LIMIT p_limit  OFFSET p_offset;

$function$
```

И ошибка :

```
ERROR:  CASE types numeric and character varying cannot be matched
LINE 42:               WHEN 'title' THEN title

                                     ^
```

А как правильно ?

Спасибо!

Comment: у вас, похоже, p_sort числом уходит

Answer (score 1):

Вы не привели DDL таблиц, но судя по всему поля `rating` и `sale_price` типа `numeric` или могут быть к нему приведены безболезненно, а вот `title` скорей всего `varchar`. Так нельзя, `CASE` должен генерировать значение только [одного типа данных](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html):

> The data types of all the result expressions must be convertible to a
>   single output type

Можно использовать явное приведение к тексту, но это очень вряд ли то, что вам нужно. Сортировка чисел как строк работает весьма логично для машины, но не очень логично - для человека.

Можно использовать второй case отдельно для текстовых данных.

Можно использовать `pl/pgsql` собирать запрос как строку, затем через `return query execute` выполнить.